# How to obtain Server.MapPath() formatted with short names (8.3 MS-DOS format)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, filesystems, directory, dos

I am using Process.Start to run a console application on the ASP.NET server and the parameters of the program need a path that is formatted in the old MS-DOS 8.3 format.

For example in a console name of the folders in this format can be obtained by typing "dir /X":

[image]

How can I obtain Server.MapPath() formatted with the short names version(8.3 MS-DOS format) of the folder names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not available as managed API...

You will need to use P/Invoke and call `GetShortPathName` on the result of `Server.MapPath()` and it will only succed if the result of `Server.MapPath()` really exists... see http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.GetShortPathName and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364989%28v=vs.85%29.aspx