# vb.net pass folder path as commandline argument

Tags: vb.net, path, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to pass a folder path via commandline argument to an application.

Problem: my folder path contains space `" "` in it's string. When I read the commandline arguments in the application I get my path chopped into pieces on the space `" "`

```
Sub Main()

    Dim arguments As String() = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
    For Each Arg As String In arguments
        Console.WriteLine("Argument : " & Arg)
    Next

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

---

Edit: added code to build my argument

```
Private Sub btn_Copy_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Copy.Click

    Dim args(3) As String
    args(0) = """" & tb_CopyFromPath.Text & """"
    args(1) = """" & tb_CopyToPath.Text & """"
    args(2) = """" & tb_ItemTag.Text & """"
    args(3) = """" & tb_Prefix.Text & """"

    Dim argument As String
    argument = args(0) & " " & args(1) & " " & args(2) & " " & args(3)

    Process.Start("J:\VB.NET - EM AddIn\EM_Design_AddIn\CopyDesign\bin\Debug\CopyDesign.exe", argument)
End Sub
```

This result isn't okay. The first argument of the first path now contains a piece of the second path.

[image: Screenshot]

---

Edit: add value result from debug.

```
"""C:\VaultWorkspace\cadcampc\03-Vessel configurator - R2.0\Nozzles\WN_RF_ASME_B16.5\"" ""C:\VaultWorkspace\cadcampc\03-Vessel configurator - R2.0\Test Copy Design\N03"" ""N3"" ""12345-3"""
```

Comment: Could you provide value for `Dim argument As String
    argument = args(0) & " " & args(1) & " " & args(2) & " " & args(3)` while debugging?

Comment: I have an idea :) Is there a chance that you entered to `tb_CopyFromPath.Text` value with double-quotes? If you enter to command line two double-quotes `""` it will be received like one. (It is the way to write double-quote in argument)

Comment: I added my msgbox result, If I'm needed to debug, i will have to change some output settings to get things going.

Comment: Okay, i Changed the result to the debug value, that doesn't look good.

Comment: @Mech_Engineer There are too many double-quotes. Each argument should has just one pair of them. Result should be  ""C:\VaultWorkspace\cadcampc\03-Vessel configurator - R2.0\Nozzles\WN_RF_ASME_B16.5\" "C:\VaultWorkspace\cadcampc\03-Vessel configurator - R2.0\Test Copy Design\N03" "N3" "12345-3""

Comment: Well, yes I can see that but how do you achieve this output? I'm totally confused..

Comment: I don't understand, if I add blockquotes either using `""""` or `chr(34)` it gives me double the amount of quotes required. When I add none nothing is added and my string is also invalid.

Comment: After what executed line of code you receive double amount?

Comment: As it is shown in my question. and suggested by @VisualVincent his solution

Comment: If you create a new application to test creating a string with double quotes, does it still add too many of them? Also, what version of Visual Studio are you using (if you are using VS, that is)?

Comment: Yes, I already checked that. Same result, my version is 2015 community ( the free one )

Comment: Do you think you could create a small project sample for me/us? Make sure that the same problems occur.

Comment: I've created a small project and the problem doesn't occur. I was wrong in my previous statement. The output is correct in the new project.

Comment: What happens if you start your application via cmd and pass arguments manually?

Answer (score 3):

It is very simple. Just use `"`.
If you pass `test test test` parameters, you'll get 3 arguments. But if you write `test "test test"`, you'll receive two parameters: `test` and `test test`.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass it with double-quotes around it.

I.e:

```
app.exe "C:\Sub folder 1\Sub folder 2"
```

If you do it in code:

```
Process.Start("app.exe", """" & path & """")
```

The quotes specifies the start and end of an argument.

---

**EDIT:**

In your case you could do this instead:

```
argument = """" & args(0) & """  """ & args(1) & """ """ & args(2) & """ """ & args(3) & """"
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for the reply. I tried implementing your answer, but failed to do so. I edited the question with more details. Maybe you can see what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest some corrections (add Trim): `Process.Start("app.exe", """" & path.Trim('""') & """")`

Comment: @user2216 : Single quotes are not valid in that context, also if the path has been constructed properly with for example `Path.Combine()` it cannot contain any double quotes.

Comment: @VisualVincent Sorry, but I cannot agree. If you add one pair of double quote `"file path"` and then one more `""file path""`, you will get two arguments `file` and `path`.

Comment: @user2216 : But `"file path"` is not a valid path, and `OpenFileDialog`s etc don't return with quotes.

Comment: @VisualVincent Yes, but before `argument = """" & args(0) & """"` there are double-quotes already after this line `args(0) = """" & tb_CopyFromPath.Text & """"`

Comment: @user2216 : He was supposed to remove that. Anyway, he can use `Trim()` if he wants and I understand and respect your opinion, but I leave it as it is for now.

Answer (score 1):

Use CHR(34) to delimiter a string with spaces within.
See my answer here:
[vb.net How to pass a string with spaces to the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097872/vb-net-how-to-pass-a-string-with-spaces-to-the-command-line)